# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Node' in plain JS after cloneNode

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, visual-studio-code, clonenode

I've got a pure JS function that adds a message to the page based on a chunk of "template" HTML.

```
const setMessage = (msg, type, msg_ct) => {
    const msg_text = document.createTextNode(msg)
    const elementToCopy = document.querySelector('#js_message_template')
    const msg_container = document.querySelector('#js_message_container')
    const clone = elementToCopy.cloneNode(true)

    clone.id = `js_message_alert_${msg_ct}`
    clone.classList.add(`alert-${type}`)
    clone.appendChild(msg_text)
    msg_container.appendChild(clone);   
}
```

VS code is complaining about `clone.id` and `clone.classList` as a Node cannot have those properties.

Now every answer and tutorial I've seen about cloning a chunk of HTML like this basically says to do exactly what I'm doing.

I can also see this is a Typescript error, though as I understand it this powers the VS Code JS checks as well, so for the moment I assume it's a valid error (?)

It makes sense that a node wouldn't have an ID like this, but what is the correct way to set the ID and add a class to the outer element of this node when I am doing this? Again, all googling leads me to examples that do exactly what I am doing!

Comment: It is essentially a TypeScript error, because `cloneNode` returns a `Node`, which, as you suspected, don't have `id` or `classList` properties. In TypeScript, you could just tack on `as HTMLElement` after `cloneNode(true)` and call it a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are cloning an HTMLElement (an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) derives from Element, which drives from Node).

Node doesn't have an `id` attributes, but `HTMLElement` (and also `Element`) does.

All you have to do is tell the compiler the cloned node is something more specific than a `Node`. E.g.

```
const clone = elementToCopy.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement;
```

If you really want to be safe, you can explicitly check for it. E.g.:

```
const clone = elementToCopy.cloneNode(true)
if (clone instanceof HTMLElement) {
  clone.id = `js_message_alert_${msg_ct}`
  ...
}
```

Up to you.

Comment: This is for a TS file though, no? I can't do this in a pure JS file ....

Comment: `as HTMLElement` won't work. He's not using TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

You could fix it by specifying what type it is with JSDOC for example:

```js
/** @type {HTMLElement} */
const clone = elementToCopy.cloneNode(true);
```

A better way would be `instanceof`:

```js
const clone = elementToCpoy.cloneNode(true);
if (clone instanceof HTMLElement) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which would work, if this was a TypeScript file, but it's a plain JavaScript file.

Comment: Oh yeah...ups...got confused

Comment: Updated my answer now